# Почему не получается вытащить файл из тела запроса?

Tags: golang, http

Только начал глядеть Go. Написал мини сервер, который принимает файл и должен записать его в каталог. Файл передается в Body, размер его в отладчике вижу не нулевой. Пробовал разными примерами из инета, ошибок нет, код отрабатывает, но файл нулевой всегда. Http-сервис, реализованный в 1с спокойно принимает эти данные и создает файл.
Что я делаю не так?!

```
func putHandler(inParam url.Values, response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {

file := gFilePath + inParam.Get("file")

tmpfile, err := os.Create(file)
defer tmpfile.Close()

//io.Copy(tmpfile, request.Body)
tmpfile.ReadFrom(request.Body)

if err != nil {
    http.Error(response, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забыл написать: в теле запроса передается файл в виде двоичных данных, т.е. не текст/json/html и подобное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В окне отладчика видно, что стрим `Body` уже прочитан - поле `sawEOF` равно `true`. Поэтому у вас нулевой файл - нечего читать.

Там, где вы прочитали содержимое `Body`, нужно сохранить его в байтовый буфер и заново  инициализировать `request.Body`. Вот пример, когда сначала тело запроса печатается в `stdout`, а затем снова используется  в запросе:

```
    body, err := io.ReadAll(request.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to read body: ", err.Error())
        http.Error(response, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    request.Body.Close()
    os.Stdout.Write(body)
    request.Body = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(body))
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось! Оказывается вызов request.ParseForm() читал body, буду знать об этом нюансе!

Comment: Академический интерес: почему разработчики так сделали, что тело можно прочитать только 1 раз, какой в этом тайный смысл?

Comment: Протокол HTTP поддерживает так называемые `chunks` - пересылку данных кусками. Когда  сервер  обрабатывает заголовки, хвост тела  ещё может передаваться. Поэтому, вообще говоря, в случае больших запросов `request.Body` обёрнут вокруг потокового читателя из сокета. Такой стрим не рестартуешь.  Вообще читать тело целиком - потенциально опасное занятие. Можно и несколько гигов зачитать. По этой причине функция `ParseMultipartForm` заранее ограничивает размер  буфера для тела.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все понятно! В данном случае мне большие файлы не грозят, т.к. сервис сугубо приватный и под конкретную задачу, где только небольшие файлы бегают.